# Need help prevent insert function from resetting in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, default

I am very new to coding. This is something I've learned, and now I'm kinda stuck right here.

My goal is to make app for android. Educational, of course.

In the mean time, I'm trying to make an app using just html. A very basic one.

Have a look below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>
<style>
table, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Set A.</p>
<table id="title">
<tr>
<td><p>Workout</p></td>
<td><p>Set</p></td>
<td><p>Rep</p></td>
<td><p>Rest</p></td>
<td><p>Remove</p></td>
</td>
<tr>
<td><form><input type="text" value="ex. BP"/><input type="reset"/></form></td>
<td><form><input type="text" value="ex. 5"/><input type="reset"/></form></td>
<td><form><input type="text" value="ex. 5"/><input type="reset"/></form></td>
<td><form><input type="text" value="ex. 60s"/><input type="reset"/></form></td>
<td><button>Remove</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td><form><input type="text" value="ex. BP"/><input type="reset"/></form></td>
<td><form><input type="text" value="ex. 5"/><input type="reset"/></form></td>
<td><form><input type="text" value="ex. 5"/><input type="reset"/></form></td>
<td><form><input type="text" value="ex. 60s"/><input type="reset"/></form></td>
<td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)">Remove</Button></td>
</tr>

</table>
<br>

<button onclick="myCreatFunction()">Add Data Row</button>
<button onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</button>
<button onclick="myNewTable()">New Table</button>

<script>
function myCreatFunction() {
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow();
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
cell1.innerHTML = '<form><input type="text" value="ex. BP"/><input type="reset"/></form>';
cell2.innerHTML = '<form><input type="text" value="ex. 5"/><input type="reset"/></form>';
cell3.innerHTML = '<form><input type="text" value="ex. 5"/><input type="reset"/></form>';
cell4.innerHTML = '<form><input type="text" value="ex. 60s"/><input type="reset"/></form>';
cell5.innerHTML = '<button onclick="deleteRow(this)">Remove</button>';
}



function myNewTable() {
var tableOne = document.getElementById("myTable");
var rowOne = tableOne.insertRow();
var cell1 = rowOne.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = rowOne.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = rowOne.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = rowOne.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = rowOne.insertCell(4);
cell1.innerHTML = '<td><p>Workout</p></td>';
cell2.innerHTML = '<td><p>Set</p></td>';
cell3.innerHTML = '<td><p>Rep</p></td>';
cell4.innerHTML = '<td><p>Rest</p></td>';
cell5.innerHTML = '<button onclick="deleteRow(this)">Remove</button>';
}



function myDeleteFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
}

function deleteRow(r) {
var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The thing is, I want them to stay intact when user closes or reopens the app. Basically, it's like a book in real life. You write,  close them, put them away, and when you pick them back up, everything's in there.

I have insertCell function that require clicking to add new row. But then it disappears/reset to default as soon as the app is closed and reopened.
The process should be: `user open > input value > add row/delete row/table>close app`.
And when the user open them up, everything is still there. it would be even better if it can be acheived without save button.

Comment: So, ofcourse you've implemented your secret automatic saving system, but something has gone wrong. What?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to make those "button results" to stay the same. Everytime I close the app, reopen, everything goes back to default. All the rows I added just disappeard. All the data, just go back to default "value"

Comment: Could use some help here. How to bump this?